# NodeJS Get form is not returning anything

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to send over some data from a form that is nested with a . I will supply code and explain it. 
EJS:

```
<%if (projects[i].status == "Created") {%>
<td>
   <form method="get" action="/updateEngineer/<%=projects[i]._id%>">
      <select name="eng">
         <% for(var k = 0; k < engineers.length; k++){%>
         <option value="teeeest"> <%=engineers[k].local.email%></option>
         <%}%>
      </select>
      </br><a   type="submit"href="/updateEngineer/<%=projects[i]._id%>"class="btn btn-success">Update Engineer</a>
   </form>
</td>
<%}%>
```

And my get on my server side:

```
router.get('/updateEngineer/(:id)', function(req, res, next){

      var o_id = new ObjectId(req.params.id).toString();
      console.log(req.body.eng);
      db.collection('projects').find({
        "_id": ObjectId(o_id).toString
      }).toArray(function(err, results) {

        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

          if (results[i]._id == o_id) {

            console.log(results[i]);



            db.collection('projects').updateOne({
              "_id": results[i]._id
            }, {

              $set: {
                "engineerEmail": req.body.eng
              }

            }, function(err) {

              console.log("success");
              res.redirect('/projects');
            });
          }

        }
      });
 })
```

It successfully calls that program but when I print req.body.eng returns undefined and when I print the req.body it returns a {}. I am not sure why it is not working, so any insight on this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: response will never be sent to client if results is empty from projects.

Comment: to get data inside req.body you need send data as a JSON object thru POST.

Answer (score 0):

Your form method is `GET` which will send form data as url parameters. You can access it inside your route handler as `req.query`.

But you should be using `POST` method to get data in `req.body`.